# How can I get data from the Identity table - AspNetUsers?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Project:

- ASP.NET 5 + use Identity
- Database in MySQL

To work with the database I use Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL package.

Using the **ApplicationUser.cs** model, I added fields to the standard Identity ***table - AspNetUsers***.

Registered users (added two entries/users to the table).

In the **UserController.cs** controller, I am trying to get data from the ***AspNetUsers table***.

But *_db.applicationuser* does not return me elements (*count = 0*).

And:

> What am I doing wrong?

> How can I get data from the Identity table - AspNetUsers?

I did if an example, but the MS SQL database was used there. I found a couple more examples, but in these cases the project did not even start.

**Data/ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```cs
    namespace localizeTest.Data
    {
        public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
        {
            public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
               : base(options)
            {
            }
    
            public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**Models/ApplicationUser.cs**

```cs
    namespace localizeTest.Models
    {
        public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
        {
            public string FistName { get; set; }
    
            public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    
            public string LasttName { get; set; }
    
            public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    
            public string UserType { get; set; }
            public string UserView { get; set; }
    
            [NotMapped]
            public  string RoleId { get; set; }
    
            [NotMapped]
            public string Role { get; set; }
    
        }
    }
```

**Controllers/UserController.cs**

```cs
    namespace localizeTest.Controllers
    {
        public class UserController : Controller
        {
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
            private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    
            public UserController(ApplicationDbContext db, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
            {
                _db = db;
                _userManager = userManager;
            }
    
            public IActionResult Index()
            {
    
                var userList = _db.ApplicationUser.ToList();
                var userRole = _db.UserRoles.ToList();
                var roles = _db.Roles.ToList();
                foreach (var user in userList)
                {
                    var role = userRole.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == user.Id);
                    if (role == null)
                    {
                        user.Role = "None";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        user.Role = roles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == role.RoleId).Name;
                    }
                }
    
                return View(userList);
            }
        }
    }
```

**StartUp.cs** - {...ConfigureServices...}

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddLocalization(opt => { opt.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
                services.AddRazorPages()
                    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
                    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
                services.AddMvc()
                    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
                    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
    
                services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
                opt =>
                {
                    var suppoortedCulteres = new List<CultureInfo>
                    {
                        new CultureInfo("ru"),
                        new CultureInfo("en")
                    };
                    opt.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("ru");
                    opt.SupportedCultures = suppoortedCulteres;
                    opt.SupportedUICultures = suppoortedCulteres;
                }
                );
    
                services.AddDNTCaptcha(options =>
                {
                    options.UseCookieStorageProvider();
                });
    
                //Database
                string connection = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
                ServerVersion version = ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connection);
    
                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseMySql(connection, version));
                services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
    
                services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
                services.AddControllersWithViews();
            }
```

P.S. Sorry for Google translate

Comment: You get the table from database, check whether the database has been created and has some value in it.

Comment: With the help of migrations, tables were created in the database. The AspNetUsers table is not empty, two users have been created in (Using the standard registration form). Authorization with these users works.

Answer (score 0):

In your **Startup.cs**, you may try to change

`services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>`

to

`services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>`

which is your custom User class

Comment: Changed it and got an error:

    `An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

    InvalidOperationException: No service for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'has been registered.`

Comment: Then you should also make changes in your UserController.cs. Change all occurrence of ```UserManager<IdentityUser>```  to  ```UserManager<ApplicationUser>```